# Move rs to method causes Exception

Tags: java, sql

I have some duplicated following code

```
rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
rs.next();
```

I want to move it to a method so that I can reuse the code. The method is like:

```
public static void point(ResultSet rs, PreparedStatement prepStmt){
        rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
        result = rs.next();
}
```

Then I want to get a column value, like, String gender = rs.getString("gender");
And I get the following exception:
java.sql.SQLException: Invalid column name gender. The error does not show up when I did't 
encapsulate the logic in the method. So the column name is correct.

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Can you share your full code? Nothing in this snippet suggests such a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to be assuming that the change to the `rs` parameter will be propagated to the calling code. It won't. Everything in Java is passed by value - including references. Instead, you should probably do something like:

```
public static ResultSet point(PreparedStatement prepStmt) {
    ResultSet rs = prepStmt.executeQuery();
    result = rs.next();
    return rs;
}
```

You'd then call it as:

```
ResultSet rs = point(prepStmt);
```

(It's not clear what `result` is either, or whether it's really worth declaring a whole extra method just to avoid calling `rs.next()` directly... especially when it means the result of `rs.next()` is somewhat obscured...)

Comment: Thanks! I will take your advice.